# wget permission error on downloading file

Tags: linux, shell

This is very basic stuff . I am trying to use wget  for downloading a file. It was working on this machine. I didn't use the machine for some 3 months . (don't know what update went in).
Now If I use wget now it says,
wget 
Cannot write to  (Permission denied)

I am in sudoers list.
Also I am not writing any webapp. When I googled it most of site says add a sudo to wget but I don't want to add sudo. How to resolve this issue ?

PS: I am able to download via browser

Comment: Have you checked owner and permissions of your current directory by doing `ls -ld`?

Comment: @ all : Just now figured it out that the directory that I am in doesn't have write permissions. My BAD :(

Comment: Indeed very basic stuff, and probably belonging to one of the other stackexchange sites :)

Answer (score 0):

The main reason is you do NOT have write permission of the directory you want to save file. You should check the permission of the directory which wget use as stdout.

From `man wget`, we can get the reason why you run wget with `sudo` also get a 'Permission denied'. The doc says 'wget -O file http://foo is intended to work like wget -O - http://foo > file'. Because of sudo can NOT be used with redirection, so you will get a error message.

The alternative way is use `wget -O - http://foo | sudo tee file`.